# Pine script - price break

Tags: pine-script

How can I plot price break when the current close is smaller than last close?
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5VOK.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `plotchar` or `plotshape` based on the condition `close < close[1]`. More information [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/annotations/Plotting_shapes_chars_and_arrows.html).